# Trouble using withColumn() when reading stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read stream data with spark using the following code:

```
eventsDF = (
  spark
    .readStream
    .schema(schema)
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
    .withColumn("time", unix_timestamp("time")  
    .cast("double")
    .cast("timestamp"))
    .csv(inputPath)
)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
'DataStreamReader' object has no attribute 'withColumn'
```

Is there an alternative for **withColumn()** in **spark.readStream()**? I just want to change the column type of my time column from string to timestamp.

Comment: can you try move `.withColumn` after `.csv`

Comment: @SMaZ, the stream job started, but all my entries are "null" , any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: @SMaZ Never mind, figured out, need to use the original type in my schema. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `.withColumn` once the Dataframe is created - after `.csv`

```
eventsDF = (
  spark
    .readStream
    .schema(schema)
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
    .csv(inputPath)
    .withColumn("time", unix_timestamp().cast("double").cast("timestamp"))
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use withColumn with readStream ?